# How to start using MVVM in Metro Applications?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, microsoft-metro

I was watching that there's applications using this pattern. For example, Bewise.Cookbook is implementing MVVM framework from Galasoft.

I want studying some labs in Windows 8, but I have my doubts about using this pattern in Metro Applications.

Someone knows a good site where teach you using Win8 with MVVM?

Comment: How about this new site called [Google](http://www.google.com)? No, seriously, this topic is broadly documented, please do some research before asking this kind of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVVM has nothing particular in Windows 8. If you don't find any tutorials about using MVVM with Windows 8, try searching for tutorials about MVVM with Silverlight.

You can also check this:

- [An Address Book Application Made in MVVM For Metro Style App in Windows 8 (Part 1)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391783/An-Address-Book-Application-Made-in-MVVM-For-Metro)
- [An Address Book Application Made in MVVM For Metro Style App in Windows 8 (Part 2)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393037/An-Address-Book-Application-Made-in-MVVM-For-Metro)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [StyleMVVM](http://stylemvvm.codeplex.com). It's an MVVM framework designed from the ground up for the Metro platform. It includes its own attribute based IoC, implementations for `ICommand` and attached command behaviors, as well as services for Tiles, Badges, Toasts and Settings Pane (charm flyout). It also supports all three languages (C#, C++/CX and HTML/JS).

To make things easy to get started there are a number of C# & C++/CX templates as well as a nice example weather app.

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation with this. This post is almost an exact duplicate of your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12763744/938695 Provide more to SO than just advertisements.

Comment: I apologize I meant to put the note at the bottom that I am the author of StyleMVVM.

That being said it wasn't intended to be an advertisement. Its an open source project geared specifically around solving the problem of doing MVVM in Metro, so I thought it was on topic for this question and the one you pointed out.

In the future I'll try and avoid responses that can be misconstrued.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [MVVM for Windows 8](http://w8mvvm.codeplex.com/) library. It is very simple. You can add its NuGet package to your project. It also has an on-line project template for visual studio. So it is very easy to start. And it is library but not a framework, so you can use only features you like.